# Javascript ajaxGrid Data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Have a problem with a Javascript ajaxGrid script(js is not my basic language so sorry if it is a stupid question)

What I'm trying to do is to set button disabled if "target_use" will be "false"

Any idea how to do that?

ps: I want to do this directly in ajax not onload()

```
   $('#table').ajaxGrid({
    tableHeading: '.table-header',
    url: '<?php echo BASE_URL?>',
    requestType: 'get',

    postContent: [
        {
            control: $("<form style='display: inline-block'>" +
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-rounded btn-info' onclick='openFormField(this)'> " +
                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" +
                "<input type='hidden' name='column_name'/> " +
                "<input type='hidden' name='target_use'/>" +
                "</button></form>"),

            properties: [
                {
                    propertyField: 'input[name="column_name"]',
                    property: 'value',
                    propertyValue: 'COLUMN_NAME'
                },
                {
                    propertyField: 'input[name="target_use"]',
                    property: 'value',
                    propertyValue: 'target_use'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

    NoRecordsFound: '<?php echo $Language->translate("No Records Found")?>',
});
```